# Relative path to png file in parent directory not working

Tags: html, image, directory, relative-path

[HTML file location and mess.png file location in parent directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4uj2.png)

I am trying to link an image to my HTML project using the relative path from the HTML file. The HTML file is in a directory that is the child of the directory that the png file is in. My understanding is that src="../mess.png" should work because I'm moving to the parent directory which contains the image file. However this has not worked and I can't figure out why.

[here is an image of the code I am using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4V1P.png)

I understand it's best practice to have the image in the same directory as the HTML file, or in a folder within the directory of the HTML file.

Comment: Using one dot, i.e. src="./mess.png" would work. Two dots (../) would refer to the folder that is one level above than the current folder.

Comment: The mess.png file is indeed one level above the directory the HTML file is in, so two dots should be correct. But I did try it with one dot and that did not work.

Comment: I also went back to try the two dots with the image being one level above the HTML file. It does work. Is it possible that there is any typo on the file extension for the image?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea why it isn't working, the file extension is spelled properly. I thought maybe it has something to do with the root directory of the png file being the iCloud Drive, but it's the same for the HTML file as well. I got in contact with a technical coach at my academy and they also did not know why it wasn't working because the syntax is correct and the files are in the appropriate locations. Regardless, image files are usually stored in the same directory or a child "images" directory of the HTML file, so it's not a big deal. Just irritating that I can't figure it out.

Comment: Actually, it has been figured out. Not by me though. Apparently Live Preview uses the directory the HTML file is in as the root directory, not allowing you to move up from that directory.